# An application of Minkowski iequality.

Tags: inequality

I am Reading this [work](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.ntnu.no%2F~lqvist%2Fp-laplace.pdf&ei=VO2DUYyVKJSC8ASJkoFI&usg=AFQjCNGuZp2M0rMJnFFmU26xVTkUWhiJfg&sig2=XQpp8GwhgHmkgfgGCLT2Pw) on page 21. In the said page, the author reach the inequality: $$\int|\zeta\nabla u^{\beta/p}|^p\leq\Big(\frac{\beta}{\beta-p-1}\Big)^p\int|u^{\beta/p}\nabla\zeta|^p$$

By using the fact that $$|\nabla(\zeta u^{\beta/p})|\leq |\zeta\nabla u^{\beta/p}|+|u^{\beta/p}\nabla\zeta|$$

and the Minkpwski inequality he conclude that $$\int_\Omega |\nabla(\zeta u^{\beta/p})|^p\leq\Big(\frac{2\beta-p+1}{\beta-p+1}\Big)^p\int_\Omega|u^{\beta/p}\nabla\zeta^p|$$

I am having trouble with the last inequality. Im my calculations it goes in the reverse direction, to wit: $$\Big(\frac{\beta}{\beta-p+1}+1\Big)^p\leq2^{p-1}\Big(\frac{\beta}{\beta-p+1}\Big)^p+2^{p-1}$$

Any light on it is appreciated. Thank You